Including jupyter notebooks in documentation using nbsphinx fails to find notebooks in upper level directory
As mentioned in some other questions 1 and 2, I set up the setting in conf.py
extensions = [
    'nbsphinx',
     ...
]

and also referenced to the notebook. It works correctly and link to notebook only if the notebooks are in the current or lower level directories not upper level, I mean
/your_project/
    ├── Makefile
    ├── conf.py
    ├── tutorials.ipynb
    ├── index.rst
    └── examples/
        └── chap_04.ipynb

but usually we put the examples not that deep in the docs/examples
how can I set up to put the notebooks like this :
/your_project/
    ├── docs/
    │   ├── Makefile
    │   ├── conf.py
    │   ├── index.rst
    │   └── tutorials.ipynb
    └── examples/
        └── chap_04.ipynb

I already tried to add path
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../examples/"))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(".."))


didn't find the file in compiling html.

This is not directly supported, see https://github.com/spatialaudio/nbsphinx/issues/170 and https://github.com/spatialaudio/nbsphinx/issues/749.
